# A term is undefined

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an issue with my main game loop. When the player is destroyed, I remove the eventListener for the game loop. However, I get an error from the collisionCheck function that a term is undefined. Even if the collisionCheck is part of the gameLoop and the eventListener has been removed.

```
if(planeHP <= 0){
    removePlayer();
}

public function removePlayer(){
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveGameObject);
    trace("removed");
}

public function moveGameObject(event:Event){
    collisionCheck();
}
```

I can see the "removed" trace before the error in the output window. The error is always from the collisionCheck function.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So what happens in collisionCheck function? Something is trying to access something that is not defined in there.

Comment: The function basically goes through the enemies and bullets arrays and verify for collisions in between them. I don't know why the collision function would be called even after I removed the eventListener.

Comment: When and how are you adding the event handler? Is it added only once? Make sure you are not accessing anything that doesn't exist in checkCollision.

Comment: The eventListener is added only once in the constructor. It might be because it's trying to access something that doesn't exist since the level has been removed but I don't know why it would even run the function after the eventListener is removed.

Comment: You can put a break point in collisionCheck and see where it is called from.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've been able to find the issue, thanks to your suggestion. I had completely forgotten to use the breakpoints. Thanks again.

Comment: You can post the solution and accept it as an answer.

Comment: I'll do that but it seems I have to wait 2 days to accept my own post as the answer. thank again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I have multiple loops in the collisionCheck and the loop calling the removePlayer wasn't the last one so it would continue on even if I remove the listener. Just had to add a return after the removePlayer() and it fixed the issue.